# Iterate through a tab then pipe delimited file using C++

Tags: c++11

I have a tsv file from a program, but I have an issue where they placed different information in one cell delimited by the pipe sign.

```
XP_017347145.1    GO:0003676|GO:0005524|GO:0006139|GO:0008026|GO:0016818
XP_017347145.1    GO:0003677|GO:0004003|GO:0005524
XP_017347145.1    GO:0005524
XP_017347145.1    GO:0004003|GO:0016818
XP_017347145.1    GO:0003676|GO:0005524|GO:0006139|GO:0008026|GO:0016818
XP_017350967.1    GO:0005515
```

I would like to convert it into just two columns like below, but it appears I am not understanding how to use the getline() function in C++.

My experience with is not that great, but the output is supposed to look like below:

```
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0003676
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0005524
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0006139
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0008026
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0016818
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0003677
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0004003
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0005524
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0005524
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0004003
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0016818
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0003676
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0005524
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0006139
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0008026
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0016818
XP_017350967.1 = GO:0005515
```

My current code in C++ fails and misses the equal signs in certain places and returns a tab instead.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    using namespace std;
    string stringIn;
    string stringOut;
    string value;
    string value2;

    cout << "Input the name of the file: " << endl;
    getline(cin, stringIn);
    cout << "The output file name is " << endl;
    getline(cin, stringOut);

    ifstream inputFile(stringIn);
    ofstream outputFile(stringOut);

    // Let the user know if the file exists
    if (!inputFile) {
        cout << "Cannot open input file" << endl;
    }

    if (!outputFile) {
        cout << "Can not save output file" << endl;
    }

    // It should iterate through the values using column
    // and column2 delimited by the pipe sign.
    // For example, GO:0005524|GO:0008026 and this could be of unknown length.
    while (getline(inputFile,value,'\t')) {
        while (getline(inputFile,value2,'|')) {
            outputFile << value + " = " + value2 << endl;
        }
    }

    outputFile.close();
    inputFile.close();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

My current code returns the following outputs and the data as shown below. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0003676
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0005524
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0006139
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0008026
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0016818
XP_017347145.1    GO:0003677
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0004003
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0005524
XP_017347145.1    GO:0005524
XP_017347145.1    GO:0004003
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0016818
XP_017347145.1    GO:0003676
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0005524
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0006139
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0008026
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0016818
XP_017350967.1    GO:0005515
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because `getline(inputFile,value2,'|')` is capturing the following:

```
GO:0016818\nXP_017347145.1\tGO:0003677
           ^
           |
           |
       newline captured
```

So then it prints an entire record without the equal sign because it was part of the previously captured `value2`.

It would be better to to do `getline(inputFile,line)` for each line with the default `\n` newline delimiter. Then use `line` to create a `std::stringstream ss{line}` and then finally run `getline(ss,value2,'|')` on that.

---

As an aside I was playing with regex and I thought the following might be a more elegant and general solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::stringstream input{R"(XP_017347145.1  GO:0003676|GO:0005524|GO:0006139|GO:0008026|GO:0016818
XP_017347145.1  GO:0003677|GO:0004003|GO:0005524
XP_017347145.1  GO:0005524
XP_017347145.1  GO:0004003|GO:0016818
XP_017347145.1  GO:0003676|GO:0005524|GO:0006139|GO:0008026|GO:0016818
XP_017350967.1  GO:0005515)"}; 

struct Record{
    std::string xp;
    std::string go;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Record& r)
{
    return os << "XP_" << r.xp << " = GO:" << r.go << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Record> records;
    for(std::string line; getline(input, line);) {
        std::regex r{R"(^XP_(\d*\.\d))"}; // match xp
        std::smatch m;
        if(std::regex_search(line, m, r)){
            auto xp = m[1].str();
            std::regex go_r{R"(GO:(\d*)\|?)"}; // match go
            auto begin = std::sregex_iterator{line.begin(), line.end(), go_r};
            auto end = std::sregex_iterator{};
            std::for_each(begin, end, [&records, &xp](const auto& i){records.emplace_back(Record{xp, i[1].str()}); });
        }
    }
    for(const auto& i : records)
        std::cout << i;
}
```

Output:

```
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0003676
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0005524
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0006139
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0008026
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0016818
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0003677
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0004003
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0005524
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0005524
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0004003
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0016818
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0003676
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0005524
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0006139
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0008026
XP_017347145.1 = GO:0016818
XP_017350967.1 = GO:0005515
```

Answer (score 2):

you can solve the problem by using sregex_token_iterator like:

```
    std::regex re("\\s+|\\|");
    sregex_token_iterator reg_end;
    while (getline(inputFile,value)) {
        sregex_token_iterator it(value.begin(), value.end(), re, -1);
        std::string p1 =  (it++)->str();
        for (; it != reg_end; ++it) {
            outputFile << p1  << " = " << it->str() << endl;
        }
   }
```

Comment: question the regular expression "\s" is supposed to be space correct but what does the extra "\" mean?